# React state-property always undefined but shown as set in developer tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm facing a very weird issue using `ReactJs` together with `TyperScript`.

I init my state with a value from the given props in the component's constructor:

```
constructor(props: IEditProps) {
    super(props);

    const initialState = {
        player: {
            id: props.user.id,
            firstName: props.user.firstName,
            lastName: props.user.lastName,
        } 
    } as IEditState;

    this.state = initialState;
}
```

In my `render`-call I will check if there is a player-object in state. If not, a search-field should be displayed where a parent player can be searched:

```
render(): JSX.Element {
    // get values from props & state
    const { user } = this.props;
    const { player } = this.state;

    console.dir(player); // shows undefined in console
    console.dir(this.state.player); // shows undefined in console

    // do more and return the markup
    return <div>...</div>;
}
```

However, `player` is always `undefined` so it always renders the search-input instead of the related player's data. 
When ckecking/hovering the state-value in Chrome's development-tools it is always set correctly.

Also when typing `this.state.player` in console it shows the correct value.

I have no idea what is going on here. Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

I already tried by adding a new `string`-property `test?: string;` to state. Initializing the same way

```
const initialState = {
    player: {
        id: props.user.id,
        firstName: props.user.firstName,
        lastName: props.user.lastName,
    },
    test: "What is going on here?"
} as IEditState;
```

the property is set/shown correctly.

### Solution/Problem

As pointed out by Pavel in the comments I checked the naming of thge property and indeed I had a typo I thought `TypeScript` would complain about.

The issue was with how I create the `initialState` casting with `as IEditState`. 
Had this rewritten to:

```
const initialState :IEditState = {
    player: {
        id: props.user.id,
        firstName: props.user.firstName,
        lastName: props.user.lastName,
    }
};
```

which then was complaining about the property not known (as of it was misspelled).

Comment: Make `console.log(this.state)`, please. I think, some other code reset value. Try to rename variable.

Comment: @Pavel I'm such an id*@t. Just found out that I misspelled the property when initializing in constructor. I thought `TypeScript` would complain about this. Unfortunately it doesn't...

Comment: TypeScript [should complain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IEditState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20player%3A%20object%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20initialState%20%3AIEditState%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20player1%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B). Looks like you doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state object correctly. `this.state = initialState` will **not re-render** your component when it runs. You need to do in the following way;

```
this.setState({
   player: {
            id: props.user.id,
            firstName: props.user.firstName,
            lastName: props.user.lastName,
        }, 
});
```

Check the official documentation about [using state correctly in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) for details.

Comment: I don't want to re-render. In the constructor the render has not yet been called. It's just to set the initial state's values. Also checked by adding another `test` property to state which works fine when initialized with `initialState`.